# Compare String with Cp1252 encoding

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

I want to process a computer-generated log file line by line. Unfortunately, the file is created with CP1252 (Notepad++ reports it's UCS-2 LE with BOM). To my shame, I am unable to find a substring in the file's lines.

```
for (String s : Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("sample.log"), Charset.forName("Cp1252"))) {
    if (s.contains("INFO"))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

fails, most likely because the strings read from file contain 2 bytes per character which appears to be not treated properly.

Assuming that the reading part is wrong: how should I read that file to cause no problems with futher string operations?

Comment: Well which is it? Cp1252 or UCS-2LE? Your question is the equivalent of "So I have an English text file (although they say it's French) and I don't understand anything about it".

Comment: `UCS-2 LE with BOM` != `CP1252` !

Comment: Thanks to both comments! If anybody would be willing to give the hint as answer, I could accept it. Specifying the charset as Cp1252 was the first soltion to avoid  `java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException` which was apparently wrong. Reading UTF-16LE works.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose would you like to handle this?

Comment: @Twonky: You can easily answer your question yourself (and accept it).